# Extracting info from a JSON: P5.js

Tags: javascript, php, p5.js

my php script json_encodes this:

```
[{"x":"20","y":"24","name":"NewNov"},{"x":"20","y":"70","name":"Tito"}]
```

But I can't see how I can extract this information in my p5.js program?

Say, I need to use those 'x', 'y', 'name' to draw a circle in the appropriate place with the right name.

I used loadJSON in the script, and now I have a variable -

```
data = loadJSON()
```

But how do I get, say, the 'x' component from the JSON?

```
var radius;

function preload() {
    var url = 'http://localhost/planetTrequest.php';
    radius = loadJSON(url);
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(300, 300);
    background(153);
    noLoop();
}

function draw() {
    background(200);
    textSize(15);
    text(radius.x, 10, 30);
    fill(0, 102, 153);
}
```

Comment: well data/radius is going to be an array so access it as such, ie: `data[0].x, data[0].y, data[1].x, data[1].name`, use loops (for, while, etc) to loop over the array

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to all the comments above, that's what worked in the end:

```
 var data;

 function preload() {
 var url = 'http://localhost/planetTrequest.php';
 data = loadJSON(url);
 }

 function setup() {
 createCanvas(300, 300);
 background(153);
 noLoop();
 }

 function draw() {
 background(200);
 textSize(15);
 text(data[0].name, 10, 30);
 fill(0, 102, 153);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is in an array with two objects (the jsons).

```
var firstObj = data[0]; // get the first element from array
var secondObj = data[1]; // get the second element
```

`firstObj.x` return you x from the first json.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I tried your variant, but it seems I did something wrong.

Comment: Can you give me a sample?

Answer (score 0):

**Just for a quick example**

Given you have an input returned as JSON like:

```
var data = [{"x":"20","y":"24","name":"NewNov"},{"x":"20","y":"70","name":"Tito"}];
```

If you want to extract `x`, `y`, `name` from each of the elements in that array, you can do:

```
for (var element of data){
    // Your element is in format : 
    // {"x":"20","y":"24","name":"NewNov"}

    // To get X
    var x = element.x; // or element["x"]
    // To get Y
    var y = element.y; // or element["y"]
    // To get name
    var name = element.name; // or element["name"]

    // Do whatsoever with your element
    // ...
}
```

** JSON is an object**

You can quickly access any property in your JSON data via its `key` as demonstrated above in the code. You basically have two ways, access with `.` property or `[]` array index notation.

Answer (score 0):

[`loadJSON`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadJSON) is asynchronous, which means the data won't be immediately available. `loadJSON` works by populating the properties on the object it returns when called inside `preload` because p5 won't call `setup` or `draw` until all asynchronous calls in `preload` have resolved.

According to the docs:

> Calling `loadJSON()` inside `preload()` guarantees to complete the operation before `setup()` and `draw()` are called.

The normal setup is as follows:

```js
let data; // expose the result object's variable globally

function preload() {
  /* endpoint to get an example JSON with a `title` property: 
      {"title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit"} 
  */
  const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1";

  data = loadJSON(url);    // get a reference to a placeholder object that 
                           // will be filled in before draw/setup

  console.log(data.title); // guaranteed to be undefined!
                           // p5 hasn't waited for the call to complete yet
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 150);
  noLoop();
  console.log(data.title); // data.title is defined!
}

function draw() {
  background(200);
  textSize(15);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  text(data.title, width / 2, height / 2); // data.title is defined!
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

When using `loadJSON` outside of `preload`, p5 doesn't do anything special to wait for the load to finish. The docs recommend supplying a callback to `loadJSON` that is called with the response data when it arrives:

```js
function setup() {
  const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1";
  //let title; // wrong! this can't expose data for this block to access
  
  loadJSON(url, data => {
    //title = data.title; // wrong! this won't set the outer 
                          // variable let title; in time for 
                          // the bottom console.log(title)
    
    // correct! now you can consume the data
    console.log(data.title);
  });
  
  //console.log(title); // wrong! title will be undefined here
  noLoop();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Keep in mind `loadJSON` is not the only way to get JSON data. You can use any other library to get the data. `loadJSON` won't be defined outside of p5 functions. On Node, [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios) is a good bet. In the browser, [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) is a good bet.

See also [Return response from asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30224774/return-response-from-asynchronous-call-example) for an in-depth guide to the callback pattern shown above. You can promisify the callback and otherwise use techniques in this thread for accessing the data from the response in a way that works for your needs (this goes beyond the scope of p5 and the normal use cases for `loadJSON`).